# Why is file uploaded into temp Directory first?

Tags: php, apache

When we upload a file using HTML Form it is uploaded to `tmp` folder on server first.
After file uploading process is completed, We need to move the File to our folders using `move_uploaded_file()` function.

Why file is first uploaded on `tmp` folder? Why can't we upload the file to our destination folder directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file isn't stored in a temp directory, then the entire thing has to be stored in memory until the script finishes running (or calls a function to remove it from memory).

Give it a few large files and the server would run out of RAM, hammer the swap partition and probably fall over.